# reformat in vim for a nice column layout

Tags: vim, reformat

I have this dataset in a csv file

```
1.33570301776, 3.61194e-06, 7.24503e-06, -9.91572e-06, 1.25098e-05, 0.0102828, 0.010352, 0.0102677, 0.0103789, 0.00161604, 0.00167978, 0.00159998, 0.00182596, 0.0019804, 0.0133687, 0.010329, 0.00163437, 0.00191202, 0.0134425 
1.34538754675, 3.3689e-06, 9.86066e-06, -9.12075e-06, 1.18058e-05, 0.00334344, 0.00342207, 0.00332897, 0.00345504, 0.00165532, 0.00170412, 0.00164234, 0.00441903, 0.00459294, 0.00449357, 0.00339737, 0.00166596, 0.00451926, 0.00455153
1.34808186291, -1.99011e-06, 6.53026e-06, -1.18909e-05, 9.52337e-06, 0.00158065, 0.00166529, 0.0015657, 0.0017022, 0.000740644, 0.00078635, 0.000730052, 0.00219736, 0.00238191, 0.00212762, 0.00163783, 0.000750669, 0.00230171, 0.00217917
```

As you can see, the numbers are formatted differently and misaligned. Is there a way in vim to quickly align the columns properly, so that the result is this

```
1.33570301776,  3.61194e-06, 7.24503e-06, -9.91572e-06, 1.25098e-05, 0.0102828,  0.010352,   0.0102677,  0.0103789, 0.00161604, 0.00167978, 0.00159998, 0.00182596, 0.0019804,  0.0133687,  0.010329,   0.00163437, 0.00191202, 0.0134425 
1.34538754675,  3.3689e-06,  9.86066e-06, -9.12075e-06, 1.18058e-05, 0.00334344, 0.00342207, 0.00332897, 0.00345504,0.00165532, 0.00170412, 0.00164234, 0.00441903, 0.00459294, 0.00449357, 0.00339737, 0.00166596, 0.00451926, 0.00455153
1.34808186291, -1.99011e-06, 6.53026e-06, -1.18909e-05, 9.52337e-06, 0.00158065, 0.00166529, 0.0015657,  0.0017022, 0.000740644,0.00078635, 0.000730052,0.00219736, 0.00238191, 0.00212762, 0.00163783, 0.000750669,0.00230171, 0.00217917
```

That would be great to copy and paste sections with ctrl-v. Any hints?

Answer (score 309, accepted):

If you're on some kind of UNIX (Linux, etc), you can cheat and filter it through the column(1) command.

```
:%!column -t
```

The above will parse on delimiters inside string literals which is wrong, so you will likely need pre-processing steps and specifying the delimiter for this file for example:

```
%!sed 's/","/\&/' | column -t -s '&'
```

Comment: For more control, I inserted tabs (could be an unused symbol) in the file to mark columns using substitution, and then ran :%!column -t -s "^I" to tabulate (C-v, tab inserts a literal tab character - ^I)

Comment: Because my files didn't have a space I had to use `:%!column -t -s ','`. It removes the commas, so they're not technicaly csv files anymore. But arranges them beautifully, which is what I needed.

Comment: Great tip! Just adding, it works for visual selection too with `:'<,'>!column -t`

Comment: The command `column -t -s '&'` deletes the separator character which is a problem when using the `&` in a LaTeX Table as separator.

Comment: also use the option ":set nowrap" for very wide files that go off the screen

Comment: Anyone know of a solution to work with quoted columns with commas in the column?  example "2151 Main ST Houston, TX"

Comment: @Thomas, you can do something like this to deal with latex tables...
    `:s/&/;;&/g`
    `:!column -t -s ';;'`

Comment: @metrix, here is a *very* clumsy workaround: 1) convert spaces inside delimiters into a different character, 2) then run `column` as described in the post, 3) then replace your delimiters back to spaces. An example command in visual mode for step #1 is: `'<,'>s/"\(\w\+\) \(\w\+\)"/"\1_\2"/g`

Comment: A reminder for Windows users: `column` and `vim` are both available via `git bash`.

Comment: Awesome!  (Stating the obvious) to minimize unintended alterations of your source file, work on a copy.

Comment: It's awesome, but is there a way to avoid removing delimiter?

Answer (score 66):

Sometimes we want to align just two columns. In that case, we don't need any plugins and can use pure Vim functionality like this:

1. Choose a separator. In OP's post this is a comma, in my example this is `=`.
2. Add spaces before/after it. I use `s/=/=  ...spaces...    /` in visual selection for this.
3. Locate to the longest word and place cursor after it.
4. Remove all the extra whitespace using `dw` and vertical movement.

Example of this technique demonstrated below:

[image: Example]

I don't find myself needing to align things often enough to install another plugin, so this was my preferred way of accomplishing it - especially that it doesn't require much thinking.

Comment: How did you make that nice gif?

Comment: http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/ unfortunately, looks like it's a Windows-only tool.

Comment: When you finished aligning the upper part, how did you move the cursor to the middle of screen and then start aligning the lower part?

Comment: I suppose with either 15↓ or 16G.

Comment: After `:s/=/         =/` it is much better to use `Ctrl + V` to select the right column, then align it using `<<` and `.` to repeat. Found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24704379/2152384

Comment: Or creaete a macro to do de job @pozitron57

Comment: After one `dw`, it would be a lot faster (and less error-prone) to go with repeated `j.` or `k.`.

Comment: Simplest then would be: `'<,'>s/^\(\S*\)/\=printf("%-48s", submatch(1))` 
One could expand it to be: 
`'<,'>s/^\(\S*\)\s*=\s*/\=printf("%-48s= ", submatch(1))` 
and it would align even if line is `foo=bar`. – 
To get format width one could do:
`max(map(getline("'<", "'>"), "match(v:val, '=')"))`
So as a one-liner:
`let w = max(map(getline("'<", "'>"), "match(v:val, '=')")) | '<,'>s/^\(\S*\)\s*=\s*/\=printf("%-".w."s= ", submatch(1))`

Answer (score 26):

As sunny256 suggested, the `column` command is a great way of doing this on Unix/Linux machines, but if you want to do it in pure Vim (so that it can be used in Windows as well), the easiest way is to install the [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin and then do:

```
:%Align ,
:%s/\(\s\+\),\s/,\1/g
```

The first line aligns the entries on the commas and the second moves the comma so that it's flush with the preceding value.  You may be able to use `AlignCtrl` to define a custom mapping that does the whole lot in one go, but I can never remember how to use it...

**Edit**

If you don't mind two spaces between entries and you want to do this in one command, you can also do:

```
:%Align ,\zs
```

Comment: Works perfectly in a LaTeX Table: `:'<,'>Align &`

Comment: It can accomplished also with `:%Align! lP0 \s` (`l` = left aligned, `P0` = 0 padding after the separator).

Answer (score 11):

This is a great answer using vim macros: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8363786/59384 - basically, you start recording a macro, format the first column, stop recording then repeat the macro for all remaining lines.

Copy/pasted from that answer:

```
qa0f:w100i <Esc>19|dwjq4@a
```

*Note the single space after the 100i, and the <Esc> means "press escape"--don't type "<Esc>" literally.*

*Translation:*

```
qa         -- record macro in hotkey a
0          -- go to beginning of line
f:         -- go to first : symbol
w          -- go to next non-space character after the symbol
100i <Esc> -- insert 100 spaces
19|        -- go to 19th column (value 19 figured out manually)
dw         -- delete spaces until : symbol
j          -- go to next line
q          -- stop recording macro
4@a        -- run the macro 4 times (for the remaining 4 lines)
```

Answer (score 11):

We now also have the fabulous [EasyAlign](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) plugin, written by junegunn.

Demonstration GIF from its README:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Also, Tabularize is quite good http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/

Comment: The `Tabularize` command (or short `Tab`) works well for csv files separated by `,` and markdown tables separated by pipes  `|`, but to make it work for tsv files, you need to use `:Tab /` followed by CTRL + V then TAB, as explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951672/how-can-i-insert-a-real-tab-character-in-vim

Comment: Mastapiece. Archive if server goes down: http://web.archive.org/web/20210309173605/http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [csv.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830) plugin.

```
:%ArrangeColumn
```

However, this will not do exactly what you have asked: it will right adjust the contents of cells, whereas you have your values aligned by the decimal point or by the first digit.

The plugin has many other useful commands for working with CSV files.

Answer (score 4):

also if you have very long columns it can be handy to disable default wrapping

```
:set nowrap
:%!column -t
```

(note in debian you also have a further option for column -n which if you want to split multiple adjacent delimiters)

Comment: much better with nowrap. I included your suggestion, thanks 'command CSV set nowrap | %!column -t -s ','`.

Comment: also, note the -n option to disable the merging of empty columns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875305/command-line-csv-viewer

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote [tablign](https://github.com/nschloe/tablign) for this purpose. Install with

```
pip3 install tablign --user
```

Then simply mark the table in vim and do

```
:'<,'>:!tablign
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a pure Vim script answer, no plugins, no macros:

It might be most clear to start out with my problem’s solution as an example. I selected the lines of code I wanted to affect, then used the following command (recall that entering command mode from visual mode automatically prepends the “'<,'>”, so it acts on the visual range):

```
:'<,'>g``normal / "value<0d>D70|P`
```

Except I did NOT actually type “<0d>”. You can enter unprintable characters on the command line by pressing ctrl-v, then the key you want to type. “<0d>” is what is rendered on the command line after I typed ‘ctrl-v enter’. Here, it’s parsed by the “normal” command as the exit from “/” search mode. The cursor then jumps to “ value” in the current line.

Then we simply [D]elete the rest of the line, jump to column 70 (or whatever you need in your case), and [P]ut what we just deleted. This does mean we have to determine the width of the widest line, up to our search. If you haven’t put that information in your statusline, you can see the column of the cursor by entering the normal mode command ‘g ctrl-g’. Also note that jumping to a column that doesn’t exist requires the setting 'virtualedit'!

I left the search term for the :g(lobal) command empty, since we used a visual block and wanted to affect every line, but you can leave off using a visual selection (and the “'<,'>”) and put a search term there instead. Or combine a visual selection and a search term to narrow things more finely/easily.

Here’s something I learned recently: if you mess up on a complex command mode command, undo with ‘u’ (if it affected the buffer), then press “q:” to enter a special command history buffer that acts much like a conventional buffer. Edit any line and press enter, and the changed command is entered as a new command. Indispensable if you don’t want to have to stress over formulating everything perfectly the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question, but I've recently availed myself of an excellent vim plugin that enables table formatting either on the fly or after-the-fact (as your use case requires):

https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode

Answer (score 0):

I made a cli tool written in Perl.

You can find it here: https://github.com/bas080/colcise

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my .vimrc.

```
command! CSV set nowrap | %s/,/,|/g | %!column -n -t -s "|"
```

This aligns the columns while keeping the comma, which may be needed later for correct reading. For example, with Python Pandas `read_csv(..., skipinitialspace=True)`, thanks Pandas guys for this smart option, otherwise in vim `%s/,\s\+/,/g`. It may be easier if your `column` has the option *--output-separator* I guess, my doesn't and I'm not sure why (my man page for column says 2004, on ubuntu 18.04, not sure ubuntu will get a new version). Anyway, this works for me, and comment if you have any suggestions.