# Commandline CSV viewer

Tags: linux, command-line, csv, cygwin

My questions is the same as
[Command line CSV viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875305/command-line-csv-viewer)
and the `column -s, -t` command answer is almost perfect - except it doesn't seem to handle empty csv fields as I'd expect. eg given input

```
col1,,col3
,col2,
```

produces:

```
col1  col3
col2
```

but I would like:

```
col1      col3
     col2
```

Is there an option to achieve the above with column command or an alternative way to achieve this? (cygwin environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the furthest thing from elegant, and it's probably something you've already thought of and are looking for a better solution, but I work around this annoyance by doing a series of sed replacements to put a whitespace in empty fields. I have these as functions in my bashrc...

```
csvcolumn() { sed -e "s/^$2/ $2/" -e "s/$2$/$2 /" -e "s/$2$2/$2 $2/g"  -e "s/$2$2/$2 $2/g" $1 | column -t -s$2 ; }
csvcomma() { sed -e 's/^,/ ,/' -e 's/,$/, /' -e 's/,,/, ,/g'  -e 's/,,/, ,/g' $1 | column -t -s, ; }
```

The first one takes two args to be able to specify the delimiter character. The second is the same thing but it only takes one arg and assumes the delimiter is a comma since that's most often what I use anyway.

```
csvcolumn input.csv ,
```

or

```
csvcomma input.csv
```

Comment: yeah you're right I was thinking the same thing, but hey it works.

Answer (score 3):

-n option exists in debian. e.g.:

```
>$ echo -e "col1,,col3\n,col2," | column -n -s, -t
col1        col3
      col2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cat and sed.

```
cat filename | sed 's/[~\],/\t/g'
```

Comment: That doesn't match the example given (`echo col1,,col3|sed 's/[~\],/\t/g'` still outputs `col1,,col3`).

Comment: Substiting with tabs can cause columns to not line up correctly if the content widths vary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a vimmer, use the [CSV plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830), which is juuust [beautiful](http://www.256bit.org/~chrisbra/csv.gif).

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tool called visidata, works really fast.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)