# Command line CSV viewer with column-alignment for LARGE files

Tags: command-line, csv

I would like to view my CSV files in a column-aligned format from the command line, with something like `less`, but my CSV files are sometimes gigabytes big, and I'm using a little computer (Netbook, 1GB RAM, 8GB HD, 1GHz processor), so I don't want to waste a lot of memory or processing power viewing the file.

I mention that I'd like to use something like `less` because I would like to be able to navigate around within the file.

`cat FILE | column -s, -t | less` is one thought, but `cat` is still going to try to print the whole file and I'm not sure how much buffering the pipes will use (if any) or what sort of caching `less` employs.

This question is similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875305/command-line-csv-viewer), but I'm specifically interested in viewing large files using minimal resources preferably already on the machine. I don't presently use VI or EMACS, and think they'd both be overkill here. VI, for instance, would be a 27MB install for a utility acting merely as a viewer.

Comment: VIM actually buffers the file as needed. It's pretty light on resources. I even use gVim on windows which works really well. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks, @Ali. I keep hearing of the goodness of VIM, but it would be a 27.1MB download onto a computer which only has 54MB to spare. This seems space-expensive for a tool I'd be using only as a viewer.

Comment: vim binary is <2MB. (And it is 7h3 b3s7 3d170r 3v3r!!!1)

Comment: @stavnir, VIM the Ubuntu repository package weighs in at ~28.2MB. Not sure what to do about this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `less` can open oversized files. Second, both `vim` (which I use with the `Largefile` plugin and with files over 8 GB) and `emacs` can do it.
But... Most of the time, viewing a big file in a 80x40 (or a bit bigger) terminal is useless... so you should filter it with something like `(f)grep` or process it with `awk`. If you want only the start or end, then there are `head` and `tail`.

HTH

Comment: Perhaps my question was ambiguous (I've clarified it). I would like to view big files using a small, navigable viewer (like less) in a column-aligned format. `head` and `tail` don't provide this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29) \ [head](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_%28Unix%29) commands.

Or even better, Download VIM source and compile it. That should be easy enough. [Version 5.8 source](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-5.8-src.tar.gz) is 1Mb before decompressing (4MB after). Enjoy.

Comment: This is a quick and dirty solution, but doesn't allow navigation within the file.

Comment: And this will provide a nicely-formatted way to view the CSV?

Comment: @stavnir: It's been a long time since I've been able to use `vim`. Do the new versions support the `:set leftright` found in `nvi` (I think that is right). Setting that value would tell `nvi` NOT to wrap the text on the screen, and you could scroll left and right (with the `w,W,$` and normal vi navigation keys (Not mouse input!)). I recall using this feature to look at files that where ~5000 chars wide. This still doesn't solve @Richard s need to expand text on CSV columns. Can emacs do it all, he asked rethorically ;-) Good luck to all.