# Convert columns and rows in readable format

Tags: regex, shell

I have a file whose entries are like:

> Time;Instance;Database;Status;sheapthres;bp_heap;fcm_heap;other_heap;sessions;sessions_in_exec;locks_held;lock_escal;log_reads;log_writes;deadlocks;l_reads;p_reads;hit_ratio;pct_async_reads;d_writes;a_writes;lock_waiting;sortheap;sort_overflows;pct_sort_overflows;AvgPoolReadTime;AvgDirReadTime;AvgPoolWriteTime;AvgDirWriteTim

02:07:49;SAN33;SAMPLE;Active;0;10688;832;72064;8;0;0%;0;0;0;0;0;0;0%;0%;0;0;0;0;0;0%;0;0;0;0
02:08:09;SAN33;SAMPLE;Active;0;10688;832;72064;8;0;0%;0;0;0;0;0;0;0%;0%;0;0;0;0;0;0%;0;0;0;0
02:08:29;SAN33;SAMPLE;Active;0;10688;832;72064;8;0;0%;0;0;0;0;0;0;0%;0%;0;0;0;0;0;0%;0;0;0;0

and want to convert this in a readable format like:

```
Time           Instance        Database
02:07:49        SAN33       SAMPLE
02:08:09        SAN33       SAMPLE
02:08:29        SAN33       SAMPLE 

  and so on..
```

I have tried `tr -s ";" "\t"` but did not get any good result.. Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `column` as follows:

```
column -s\; -t your_file
```

where `-s\;` says that your column delimiter is a semicolon (protected with a backslash to avoid interpretation by the shell). See also [Command line CSV viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875305/command-line-csv-viewer).

Comment: Its running fine on linux server but not found in AIX system.

Answer (score 0):

How about more unix aware variant:

```
cat <your file> | sed 's/;/\t/g'
```

***Solaris*** and ***HP-UX*** users note: instead of `\t` character typing, use `Ctrl+V` and then `TAB` key sequence.