# creating a bash function to print csv to screen

Tags: bash, csv

I'm trying to create a bash function that will, once the user inputs an item code, print a csv file to the screen.

For example, when the item code is 526, I want the following to occur.

```
wget -O stats.zip "http://data.un.org/Handlers/DownloadHandler.ashx?DataFilter=itemCode:526&DataMartId=FAO&Format=csv&c=2,3,4,5,6,7&s=countryName:asc,elementCode:asc,year:desc"

zcat stats.zip
```

Is there a way to encapsulate all of this into one general function? How would one go about this using a bash script? For example, if I pass in the value XYZ, I want my script to do

```
wget -O stats.zip "http://data.un.org/Handlers/DownloadHandler.ashx?DataFilter=itemCode:XYZ&DataMartId=FAO&Format=csv&c=2,3,4,5,6,7&s=countryName:asc,elementCode:asc,year:desc"

zcat stats.zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function dl {
 wget -O stats.zip "http://...?DataFilter=itemCode:$1"; 
 unzip -c stats.zip | columns -s, -t; 
}
```

1. You can use unzip's "-c" command to [print the content of files](https://superuser.com/questions/462788/read-the-contents-of-a-zipped-file-without-extraction)
2. Bash (and other shells) allow you to wrap statements into [functions](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html)

Additionally I've used the `column` command in order to [format the CSV output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875305/command-line-csv-viewer).

You can call the function with the ItemCode as parameter: `dl 526`

Comment: You could still improve this without the temporary file.  `wget -O - "http://blah?DataFilter=itemCode:$1&moreblah" | unzip -c`

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, using `unzip --help`, I can't see an option to `unzip` that would assist in this (but I was looking at an old version, `UnZip 5.52 of 28 February 2005, by Info-ZIP` as shipped with Mac OS X 10.10.5).  The `-M` option pipes through `more`, but that is just the list of file names as they're extracted, not the contents of the files.  So, if that was the whole story, you'd need to unzip to extract the file, and then `cat` the extracted file, and then remove the extracted file and probably the zip file.

Yes, you can write a script (or even a function — though to my antiquated mind, a script is more appropriate) to do this.

OTOH, if you go to the [Info-Zip](http://www.info-zip.org/) home page, you can find that the current version is Unzip 6.0 released in 2009, and the [documentation](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html) says it supports the `-c` option to

> *extract files to stdout/screen (''CRT''). This option is similar to the `-p` option except that the name of each file is printed as it is extracted, the `-a` option is allowed, and ASCII-EBCDIC conversion is automatically performed if appropriate. This option is not listed in the unzip usage screen.*

This is consistent with other compressor and decompressor commands, such as `gzip`, `bzip2`, `xz`, and so on.  So, there might be a `-c` option in the older version, and a quick experiment shows that there is in version 5.52.

So, if you have a recent enough version of `unzip` (for an ill-defined value of 'recent enough'), you can use:

```
unzip -c stats.zip
```

to send the contents of `stats.zip` to standard output.

> How would I script this though?

Same as you would any other script: write the commands you want executed in the script.  If you want to supply the item code as an argument, you can write code to require one or more arguments and pass those to the programs.  One of the nice things about shell scripts is that the basics of a shell script are exactly what you'd type at the terminal to do the same job.  This is in contrast to a C program, for example.

For example:

```
trap "rm -f stats.zip; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

for item in "$@"
do
    wget -O stats.zip "http://data.un.org/Handlers/DownloadHandler.ashx?DataFilter=itemCode:$item&DataMartId=FAO&Format=csv&c=2,3,4,5,6,7&s=countryName:asc,elementCode:asc,year:desc"
    zcat -c stats.zip
done

rm -f stats.zip
trap 0
```

If given no arguments, this does nothing.  For each argument it is given, it gets the information from the web site, unzips the file content to standard output, and goes back for the next item.  At the end, it removes the `stats.zip` file.  It has protection so that if it is interrupted, the file is removed.  The `trap 0` at the end cancels the exit trap, so the script can exit successfully.

You should probably make the intermediate file into a better (unique) name, probably using `mktemp` command:

```
tmp=$(mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/items.XXXXXX")
```

and then use `$tmp` where the code uses `stats.zip`.