# Align text only on first separator in VIM

Tags: vim, alignment

Suppose I have this code:

```
width: 215px;
height: 22px;
margin-top: 3px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #999999;
```

I want to align it this way:

```
width:            215px;
height:           22px;
margin-top:       3px;
background-color: white;
border:           1px solid #999999;
```

using Align.vim I can do `:Align \s` to use whitespace as separator, but that has 2 problems

1. the initial indent is doubled
2. **all** whitespaces are considered separators, so the last line is messed up

I've read through the many options Align.vim offers, but I haven't found a way to do this.

Comment: For small yet relatively universal alignment tricks that work without plugins, see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7538363/254635) to the question "[Inserting indentation for columns in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7529029/254635)".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use [Tabular](http://github.com/godlygeek/tabular), then you can just do `:Tabularize /:\zs/`.

Looking at Align's description on vim.org, a similar invocation should work for it.  You could try `:Align :\zs`.  I don't use Align, so I'm not positive.

Comment: Yeah, that works with Align. You may want to use `:AlignCtrl l:` (or similar) to have any further colons disregarded.

Comment: Could someone explain what `\zs` means?

Comment: Using `\zs` will match everything before `\zs` but put it back in the results. That is, it will leave whatever you have before `\zs` intact (just as if you would have put a group `(...)` around it and used `\1`  first in the replacement. See `:h /\zs`

Answer (score 30):

You can do this with a Vim macro, no plugins needed. Put the cursor anywhere on the first line, and type in normal mode, not insert mode:

```
qa0f:w100i <Esc>19|dwjq4@a
```

Note the single space after the 100i, and the <Esc> means "press escape"--don't type "<Esc>" literally.

Translation:

```
qa         -- record macro in hotkey a
0          -- go to beginning of line
f:         -- go to first : symbol
w          -- go to next non-space character after the symbol
100i <Esc> -- insert 100 spaces
19|        -- go to 19th column (value 19 figured out manually)
dw         -- delete spaces until : symbol
j          -- go to next line
q          -- stop recording macro
4@a        -- run the macro 4 times (for the remaining 4 lines)
```

And yes, I used a similar macro to format the above code block :)

[Cf. my answer to a similar Vim alignment question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8363443/57490).

To apply this to a number of lines in visual mode, do, select and type:

```
:norm!@a
```

Comment: great that you followed up with the explanation - without it I wouldn't dare type this magical incantation, for fear of my soul and disk contents, but with it I'll even learn a few new interesting (albeit perversely) vim commands!

Comment: @TalkLittle excellent use of a plugin-free solution that does not require any additional addons. Excellent use of a commented vim command to help new users. All good practice in supporting and explaining the power of native vim.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize [@TalkLittle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57490/talklittle)'s algorithm, this can be done with this code, which is a little bit easier for the eyes to me:)

- add enough spcaes after the first colon

  `:%s/^[^:]:\zs/`*lots of spaces*`/`
- but if pressing spaces all the time hurts your thumb, use this instead

  `:%s/^[^:]:\zs/\=repeat(' ',100)/`
- then delete all spaces after column 19

  `:%s/\%19v\s*//`

  NOTE: % will do this on all lines, specify a range if you don't want this.
- if you don't feel like to count to 19, use this:

  `%s/:\zs.*// | %s/.*/\=len(submatch(0))/ | sort! n | let n=getline(1) | undo | echo 'the column nmuber of the right most ":" is' n`

Comment: extra points  for a solution that does not require any plugins

Answer (score 1):

You still can do it with your preferred plugin `Align.vim` with command:

```
Align! lp0P0: \s
```

`Align!` means that first argument is `AlignCtrl` format where you order
the first match to be left (`l`) aligned without spaces padding (`p0P0`) and you also want to skip (`:`) all subsequent matches. 
This example could be expanded for more sophisticated alignments.

Comment: I have a similar question, but don't want the padding in the OP's question.  I have tried altering your answer as :Align! 1:      and :Align! 1: \s   and :Align 1: etc., but have not found how to use something similar to your response to get Align to only align about the first :.  How would I do that?