# vim alignment plugin

Tags: vim, plugins, alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert spaces up to column X to line up things in columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154306/how-to-insert-spaces-up-to-column-x-to-line-up-things-in-columns)

Is there any plugin to make:

```
var joe = 'joe';
var johnny = 'johnny';
var quaid = 'quaid';
```

turn into:

```
var joe    = 'joe';
var johnny = 'johnny';
var quaid  = 'quaid';
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Look here:

[Align.Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294)

[Tabular](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3464)