# vim: command to push text to same x coordinate as another line

Tags: vim

I'm not sure the right words to use to express what I want, which is why I'm probably having trouble finding it myself. I have a css-like file:

```
attr_of_super_long_length: value1,
shorter_attr: value2,
medium_length_attr: value3
```

I want to be able to put my cursor over the *v* in *value1* and copy its x coordinate, and then go to the *v* in *value2* and push it to the same indented x coordinate in 1 keystroke (*eg, not highlight and > <*). Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129519

Comment: The best way to explain what you want to achieve is often to show a before/after example.

Answer (score 1):

There are some great plugins for alignment like [Align](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align) and [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular). I used Align for a while, but I've moved to tabular because I like [this](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/) [functionality](http://connermcd.com/blog/2012/05/20/pandoc-table-editing-in-vim/) for making tables. In tabular you could accomplish this by visually selecting these values and then doing the command `:Tab /:\zs` using standard vim regex (see `:help pattern`). As Tom Whittock mentioned, this question has already been asked and solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129519).

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to left-align to a particular column, but not the entire line (like `:left` does), but only the text to the right of the cursor.

Fortunately, I have written a plugin for that, and I published it right now: [AlignFromCursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4155)

With the cursor on the `v` of `value2` in your example, you press `28<Leader>le` or issue `:LeftAlignFromCursor 28`, and it'll result in this:

```
attr_of_super_long_length: value1,
shorter_attr:              value2,
medium_length_attr: value3
```

For `value3`, you can simply repeat with `.`