# Format text as blocks (aligning second column)

Tags: vim, text-formatting

A lot of times, I have a list of initializers in some of my code, like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.foo       = data.getFoo()
        self.bar       = data.getBar()
        self.something = data.getSomething()
```

As you can see, I like my code aligned like a table. In a lot of cases, the above code can be generated by scripting Vim, coming from the output of some other program (`DESCRIBE "foo";` in a database for example). Unfortunately, the scripted output usually looks like this, first:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.foo = data.getFoo()
        self.bar = data.getBar()
        self.something = data.getSomething()
```

So after the automatic generation of th assignment statements, I'll have to manually align all statements for the desired look.

Now: Is there a way to get vim to align those "second halves"of the statements automatically?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly how you obtain this output? With `:r something`?

Comment: I found a vim script that purports to do this, but I don't want to post it as an answer because I haven't actually used it: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294 . See also this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964953/align-text-on-an-equal-sign-with-vim

Comment: @romainl - The source could be anything from pasted/processed SQL to a file listing to whatever.. might be read by doing some `:r! ... ` or anything, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [tabular plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) does exactly this. You can see it in action (and learn how to use it) [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/).

UPDATE: I'll give a brief explanation about the plugin usage, but no explanation will be better then [Drew's video](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/), so I strongly suggest everybody to watch it.

To use the plugin just call `:Tab /=` and it will align **all the equal signs in the file**. If you want to specify which line you want to align just give it a range `:5,10Tab /=` or use the visual mode (`v` or `V`) to select the desired lines, press `:` and insert the Tabularize command, your command line will look like this: `:'<,'>Tab /=`.

The argument in the `Tab`command is a Regular Expression, this means you can use this command to align many things. You'll be restricted only by your Regular Expression knowledge.

Sorry for any English mistake :D

Comment: Perfect, I hope I will rememver when I need it ... To make the answer even better, you could explain how to use it in the example (like `:Tab /=`).

Comment: @mliebelt I've added a quick explanation. But as I said, no explanation I gave will be better then Drew's video.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the already mentioned *Tabular* plugin is the venerable [Align plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294).

Answer (score 0):

One naive approach would be to first make enough space around the equal signs:

```
:s/=/                         =/
```

Then, block-selecting (`Ctrl-V`) so that all the `=` characters and everything that follows is selected. Yank(`y`) that, paste it somewhere else.

Next, un-indent the pasted lines (`10<` is usually sufficient) until they're aligned to the leftmost position. Then, block-select again and paste to where they were cut off.

This feels like a lot of work though, for the desired effect.

Comment: indeed a lot of work. why not a simple :s that just adds enough tabs/spaces to all lines except the line with the longest identifier before the =