# How to format this thing in vim?

Tags: vim

I got something like this in vim:

```
awqwq:bsak
cslqw:aslkjqwd
ska:jsqpwiq
salsqwqw:wpqwi
```

How to change it quickly to this:

```
awqwq              :   bsak
cslqw              :   aslkjqwd
ska                :   jsqpwiq
salsqwqw           :   wpqwi
```

Comment: This answer to another question answer yours https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414916/29125

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reformat in vim for a nice column layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229900/reformat-in-vim-for-a-nice-column-layout)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Thanks @Eineki , I'am on windows, but It's good to use `sed` and `dw` to solve this, I will try the second on my raspi.

Answer (score 3):

Save the following macro:

```
f:40i ^[l4a ^[20|dt:j0
```

to register `a`. Then place the cursor at the beginning of the text and repeat the macro with `4@a`. In this macro `^[` is the escape character which can be obtained from insert mode by typing `<ctrl-v><esc>`.

Comment: I don't understand `^[14a` and `j0` ....could you explain this, thanks~

Comment: @leavesdrift the macro means `f:` find the : in the line (go there), `40i ` insert 40 spaces before :, `^[` press <ESC>, `14a ` insert 14 spaces after :,  `^[` press <ESC>,  `20|` go to the 20th column `dt:` remove the spaces from 21 to the : char, `j` go to the next line, `0` place the cursor on the first char.

If you go to the first line you have to format and press `qa` you will start record a macro on key a that will last until you exit the file. Just type the keysequence @Sergio gave you and then press q to save it.  invoke it with _n_@a to apply it to the next _n_lines from the cursor

Answer (score 0):

Two regex can fit this:

```
:%s/:/           :    /g
:%s/\(^[^,]\{13}\)\s\+/\1
```

This second one just capture first 13 characters, followed by blank spaces, replacing to maintain only the capture group.