# How to align (to a tabular form) lines in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi, text-alignment

I have a text file of the form:

```
line one 1 Sun
line two 22 Mon
line three 33 Tue
line four 444 Wed
```

How can I vertically-align the columns at specific places (say, the 3rd word)? The required output is:

```
line one   1 Sun
line two   22 Mon
line three 33 Tue
line four  444 Wed
```

Update: the intention was for a native Vim solution. I am aware of a few plugin-based solutions. See comments below for the chosen solution that worked for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+align+table

Comment: See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20670/18609) for a flexible way to do custom alignment on Vim. In your case, for example, you can use `:normal 2W9i ` to insert leading spaces to the third column and then left-flush from there (using visual block mode and the `<` command.) I strongly recommend learning that technique, it's the most flexible approach for alignment in Vim.

Comment: Thanks for the recommended similar question. I used the solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24065725/274579

Answer (score 5):

What I would do in command mode (not exactly what you asked):

```
%!column -t
```

Comment: OP wants to align only on a single column...

Comment: Added disclaimer

Comment: I believe a simpler version of your answer is `%!column -t`

Comment: Apparently, `column` is supported by Cygwin bash. However, the `-t` option will determine every word as a separate column, which is not what I intended (see the sample output). Specifically in my actual case, I wanted to "columnize" at an assignment operator (`=`) so I could define that character using the `--output-separator` command option.